# How to find representative summary statistic(s) for this dataset of transactions?

Tags: variance, mean

Sorry if this is inappropriate for this SE but here goes:

I have a set of data like so:
[image]

This is a histogram of transaction values (in dollars). In total there's about 5000 items in my data set. The trick here is that about 20 of them are transactions at about 25,000 dollars and then another 40 are around 75,000 dollars. For this reason I can't just take the mean of the set of data because it comes out to 
 about 3,000 dollars which is obviously not representative. Looking at this data I'd guess the average transaction is about $280.

So my question is: do I just remove the 60 items from the set of data and recalculate the mean? This feels wrong to me. I wanted to use Gaussian distribution here but the data doesn't seem to be normally distributed here. Can someone give me some information on a more accurate way to find an average transaction value for my data?

Comment: Am I correct in interpreting the x-axis as "Price (\$)" from \$0.00 to \$1000.00? The effect of which is that the 60 items you discuss (at \$25,000 and \$75,000) are not shown on the graph?

Comment: The fallacy here is that the mean must be "representative", however defined. Not so. It's convenient if mean and (major) mode are similar, but there is no obligation either on the data or on the researcher to ensure that this is so.

Comment: Have you thought of reporting the median?

Comment: There is an extra nuance. Means make sense if totals make sense, regardless of whether the underlying distribution is very skewed. Thus a company could have a few relatively large customers and many smaller ones, but the mean transaction is still quite well defined (in a given time period).

Comment: @user77876 correct. Sorry I should've mentioned.

Comment: @NickCox The problem states that the average they calculated isn't the desired value, and I took the mean and got the same value as their calculated average.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For skewed data, generally a median is a good way for a summary statistic, however:

When summarizing your data in a statistic, you really have to think about what the main take-away should be, what do you expect this number to provide. It seems that a single statistic might not give a good summary of your data, since there is more happening than could be described in one value.

I see 3 alternative options:

- [Standard way] Maybe, instead of showing 1 statistic, you might want to  show several, such as the quartiles (minimum, 25%-value, median, 75%-value, maximum)
- [Case-specific] You are saying that there might be clusters in the data - maybe it would be better to find a good split point and saying "x% of my data is below splitpoint Z and clustered around a mean of X, (1-x)% of my data is above splitpoint Z clustered around a mean of Y", and maybe give some insight into what gave rise to this formation
- [Different angle] As suggested below, you might be interested in modes, which will tell you what a "frequent type of value" is, subject to the same comments as in [Case-specific]

Comment: Helpful general advice (+1): adding a comment on modes might be a good way to extend.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different measures that can be called an "average" which include (but not limited to) the arithmetic mean, geometric mean, harmonic mean, self-weighting mean, trimmed mean, median, and sometimes the mode.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median

The median is often preferred for skewed data since it is not affected by outliers, but the geometric mean also down weights outliers to the right (but has issues if any of the data is negative or 0).

Which is best depends on the science behind what you are doing and what you are trying to accomplish.

What are you trying to accomplish?  You may still be able to use the normal if doing inference on the mean due to the Central Limit Theorem, but make sure your sample size is large enough to overcome the skewness in the data (and don't make predictions using the normal, since there is obvious skew).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do with your summary statistic/underlying model of the data, I would recommend modelling your dataset as a Mixture Model.

In this specific dataset, it looks as if there might be four underlying groupings of transactions - each with its own frequency of occurring, mean, median, variance, etc. You could see the dataset, then, as four separate Gaussians ($G_i=1...4$), each with its own probability of being selected. Roughly estimating from your histogram and description:

$P(G=i)=[0.394, 0.594, 0.004, 0.008]$

and then each Gaussian appropriately parameterized.

$G_1 = (\mu = 160.00, \sigma = 35.00)$

$G_2 = (\mu = 360.00, \sigma = 50.00)$

$G_3 = (\mu = 25000.00, \sigma = ?)$

$G_4 = (\mu = 75000.00, \sigma = ?)$